# How to preserve formatting and protect the code from scripts

Tags: php, html

I am trying to find a way to escape the scripts or tags inserted to my database and at the same time preserve the text formatting. However I bumped into several problems that only solved either of the two.
I'm trying to do it in `$blog['title']` and `$blog['content']`

I tried using `nl2br()` to preseve the formatting. It works on preserving the formatting but it still does not escape HTML tags and scripts.

These are my codes.
*Please note that I am using class where all my functions are there and instantiated the class in my current blog page.*

Blog Post HTML Block

```
<?php
                            if(isset($_GET['id'])){
                                $selectedBlog = $cakeOrdering->get_data("SELECT blogID, title, content, img, author, dateCreated FROM blogs WHERE blogID = ?", array($_GET['id']));
                                if(is_array($selectedBlog) || is_object($selectedBlog)){
                                    foreach($selectedBlog as $blog){
                        ?>
                        <!-- Blog Posts -->
                        <div class="blog_item">
                            <div class="blog_img">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="../img/blogs/<?php echo $blog['img']; ?>" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="blog_text">
                                <div class="blog_time">
                                    <div class="float-left">
                                        <a href="#"><?php echo $blog['dateCreated']; ?></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="float-right">
                                        <ul class="list_style">
                                            <li><a href="#">By :  <?php echo $blog['author']; ?></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">category</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Comments: 8</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <a href="#"><h4><?php echo $cakeOrdering->escape($blog['title']); ?></h4></a>
                                <p style="word-wrap: break-word;"><?php echo $cakeOrdering->escape(nl2br($blog['content'])); ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php }}} ?>
```

I have created a function I called escape in my php class

```
// Escaping characters
public function escape($string){
    echo htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

if I use this:

```
$cakeOrdering->escape(nl2br($blog['content']));
```

it outputs:
[image: output1]

but if I remove the escape function like this

```
nl2br($blog['content']);
```

it outputs: (preserved formatting but also executes the script)
[image: alert]
[image]

Comment: Did you mean `return htmlspecialchars` instead of `echo htmlspecialchars`?

Comment: It seems to be working for both echo and return.

Comment: oh thank you. it works just now. it looks like `return htmlspecialchars` works, and I combined whatt @Vilx- suggest. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it the other way round:

```
nl2br($cakeOrdering->escape($blog['content']));
```

Comment: It does not display the `<br>` tags any more, only the script tag is printed as it is. but it isn't still formatted.

Comment: Maybe try putting `<pre>...</pre>` around it?

Comment: i tried putting `<pre>...</pre>` around it but it outputs like this picture [link](https://ibb.co/gPS4LGf) even though it has `word-wrap` and `overflow: hidden` css property.

Comment: Thank you it works now. I called it the other way around and it seems that I have to write `return htmlspecialchars()` insted of `echo htmlspecialchars()`. howevern I don't understand why it happens. Thank anyway.

Comment: @RoyHarper - Then you need to learn more about PHP and how it works.